# Replacing Price and Image in jQuery: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

Each time a user selects a different product, the price updates. It worked fine until I wanted to update the image as well, because each different product has a different image. This is my code:

```
var productData = {
"50g": [5.00, "img/x1.jpg"], /*placed values in an array*/
"100g": [9.00, "img/x2.jpg"],
"250g": [22.00, "img/x3.jpg"],
"500g": [42.00, "img/x4.jpg"],
"1kg": [84.00, "img/x5.jpg"]
}

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.each(productData, function (key, value) { /*value or value[0] ?*/
            $("#weight").append($("<option>", {
                "value": key,
                "text": key
            }));
        });
        updateHandler();
    });
    $("#weight").on('change', updateHandler);
    $("#qty").on('input', updateHandler);
});

function updateHandler(e) {
    var value = $("#weight").val();
    var quantity = $("#qty").val();
    var price = productData[value[0]]; /*Was [value]*/
    var endPrice = price * quantity;
    $("#totalDisplay").html("$" + endPrice.toFixed(2)); /*Error: Displaying as NaN. parseInt() and parseFloat() did not work. */
    /*3 new lines of code:*/
    var oldImg = $("#productImg").attr("src");
    var newImg = productData[value[1]];
    $("#productImg").attr("src", oldImg.replace(oldImg, newImg)); /*Error: Images are not defined*/
}
```

There aren't any syntax errors (according to the console).

Here is the live demo:
www.unidrones.co.za/ChoiceGelatin/order.php

The previous (working) version:
www.fishgelatine.co.za/order

Comment: @Hikarunomemory That's true, according to the answer you referenced... However it was working fine until I added the new lines of code (which is commented). The images are not "defining" when I run the example, and suddenly the price returns a NaN.

Comment: @JDoe there is nothing wrong with the way you're using `append()` at all. It's hard to diagnose an issue without seeing a working example, though. Could you please edit the question to include the HTML, preferably in an executable snippet.

Comment: The `value` in `updateHandler` is a string, so `value[0]` would be the first character in the `value`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've edited the question and uploaded both the working and non-working versions. Thank you for looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `updateHandler()`, `value` is a string, so `value[0]` would be the first character of `value`, hence `productData[value[0]]` will not get what you want.

`var price = productData[value[0]];` should replace with `var price = productData[value][0];`. `productData[value]` would get the array of data from `productData` and then get the first item in this array which is the price of the product.

And the same goes for the `newImg`, `productData[value[1]]` should replace with `productData[value][1]`.

You can see the value of `newImg` below in the snippet's console.

```js
var productData = {
  "50g": [5.00, "img/x1.jpg"],
  "100g": [9.00, "img/x2.jpg"],
  "250g": [22.00, "img/x3.jpg"],
  "500g": [42.00, "img/x4.jpg"],
  "1kg": [84.00, "img/x5.jpg"]
}

$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // value here would be an array, value[0] is the price and value[1] is the img's url
    $.each(productData, function(key, value) {
      $("#weight").append($("<option>", {
        "value": key,
        "text": key
      }));
    });
    updateHandler();
  });
  $("#weight").on('change', updateHandler);
  $("#qty").on('input', updateHandler);
});

function updateHandler(e) {
  var value = $("#weight").val();
  var quantity = $("#qty").val();
  var price = productData[value][0];
  var endPrice = price * quantity;
  $("#totalDisplay").html("$" + endPrice.toFixed(2));
  //var oldImg = $("#productImg").attr("src");
  var newImg = productData[value][1];
  console.log(newImg)
  //$("#productImg").attr("src", oldImg.replace(oldImg, newImg)); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="weight"></select>
<input id="qty" value="1" />
<p id="totalDisplay"></p>
```

Comment: So my only mistake was the "nested" array? You're a star for catching that one :) The function is now working perfectly.